# Duplicate items in list after an API update

Tags: vue.js, key, axios, v-for

I'm learning vuejs and I'm doing a weather app, the goal is to rank cities with an index (humidex). I fetch weather information by API (axios) in order to collect data from several cities. I want to auto update data every x minutes, problem : some of my results are duplicated (the new data don't replace the old one).

I tried to set an unique key (based on latitude and longitude) for each item, it works for several results but not for all.

```
  data () {
    return {
      items:[],
      show: false,
      cities: cities,
      newCity:''
    } 
  },
  components: {
    Item
  },
  computed: {
    sortHumidex() {
      return this.items.slice().sort((a,b) => {
        return this.getHumidex(b) - this.getHumidex(a) || b.current.temp_c - a.current.temp_c
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addCity() {
      if (this.newCity.trim().length == 0) {
        return
      }
      this.cities.push(this.newCity)
      this.newCity = ''
    },
    getHumidex: (el) => {
      const e = 6.112 * Math.pow(10,(7.5*el.current.temp_c/(237.7+el.current.temp_c)))
      *(el.current.humidity/100)
      return Math.round(el.current.temp_c + 5/9 * (e-10))
    },
    indexGeo: (e) => {
      const lat = Math.round(Math.abs(e.location.lat))
      const lon = Math.round(Math.abs(e.location.lon))
      return lat.toString() + lon.toString()
    },

    getApi: function () {
      const promises = [];

      this.cities.forEach(function(element){
        const myUrl = apiUrl+element;
        promises.push(axios.get(myUrl))
      });
      let self = this;

      axios
        .all(promises)
        .then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
          responses.forEach(res => self.items.push(res.data))
      }))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getApi()
    this.show = true
  }
}
```

The render when I update API  :

[image: screenshot]

Comment: At a glance, it looks like you are pushing to `items` rather than replacing it. That seems like it would lead to the sort of problems you are encountering. Is there are reason you chose to implement it that way?

Comment: No particular reason, this is my first semi advanced dev with Vue, so I tried things :)

Comment: So does it work if you replace `responses.forEach(res => self.items.push(res.data))` with something like `self.items = responses.map(res => res.data)`?

Comment: It works, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By pushing to the existing array of items, you have to deal with the possibility of duplicates. This can be eliminated simply by **replacing** `items` every time the API call is made.

Replace:

```js
responses.forEach(res => self.items.push(res.data))
```

with:

```js
self.items = responses.map(res => res.data)
```